# Considerations for moving a function inside or outside of an integral

Tags: lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Excluding the possibility that $A(t)$ is the limit of a sequence, are there any special considerations I should be concerned with regarding the following assertion:

Let $A(t)$ be an $n\times n$ matrix of real valued functions.
Then 
$\int_0^t \left(A(x)A(t)-A(t)A(x)\right) dx = \left(\int_0^t A(x)dx\right)A(t)-A(t)\left(\int_0^t A(x)dx\right)$

Comment: This should be fine. See if you can prove it!

Comment: :D   I guess I was just being anxious that I might have forgotten something.   The proof should just be a matter of moving a finite value inside and outside of a limit$\ldots$